# How to Augment the NextPage Typescript Type

Tags: typescript, next.js

So I am coding a dashboard with roles in NextJS and want to pass in an auth object per page off of the default export like so:

[Code Example of Student Dashboard Home Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWjI9.png)

I am getting a typescript error on the Stu_HomePage.auth section saying "Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'FunctionComponent<{}> & { getInitialProps?(context: NextPageContext): {} | Promise<{}>; }'.ts(2339)"

Now how do I augment the NextPage Type to optionally contain the auth object...

Does it have something to do with the ".d.ts" files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
import type { NextPage } from 'next';

type NextPageWithAuth = NextPage & {
  auth?: {
    role: string
  }
};

const Page: NextPageWithAuth = () => {
  return <></>
}

Page.auth = {
  role: "STUDENT"
}
```